# Se puede cambiar el tipo de dato (Listas Enlazadas)

Tags: c

[image: lista]

Buenas, Hace poco empecé a utilizar este tipo de estructura y he estado implementando funciones para manejarlas. Mi duda viene al darme cuenta de que para cada tipo de dato tengo que crear una función aparte.

```
struct ejemplo{
  int valor;
  struct ejemplo *sgte;
 };
```

```
void agregar(struct ejemlo **nodo ,struct ejemlo **inicioLista){ /*Si quisiera usar otro tipo de struct 
tendría que hacer otra función o reciclar infinitamente este código para cada estructura diferente. */
  <Codigo random para interactuar con los nodos y los punteros>;
}
```

La pregunta es existe algún modo de cambiar los tipos de datos pasados por referencia ? para así hacer una función genérica ?
O en su defecto alguna forma distinta de manejar estas estructuras?.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Buen día, podrías crear una forma de plantillas (Templates) [aquí](https://levelup.gitconnected.com/using-templates-and-generics-in-c-968da223154d) te dejo un artículo que habla de como implementarlos

Answer (score 0):

Entiendo que la pregunta es para una lista en la que habrá distintos tipos de datos a la vez. Depende de qué tipos de datos quieras tener. Por ejemplo, si son datos simples como int, float, char, etc., puedes crear una **unión** y usarla como datos. Además creo que sería conveniente incluir un campo en tu estructura que indique el tipo de dato que contiene. Sería conveniente, en este caso, usar constantes, pero aquí supondré que 0=char, 1=int, 2=float.

Definimos una unión como sigue:

```
typedef union{ 
  char datoChar; 
  int datoInt;
  float datoFloat;
} TDato;
```

Una **union** es una estructura en la que todos los campos comparten la misma memoria.

Ahora tu estrructura debería ser algo así:

```
struct ejemplo{
    TDato valor;
    char tipoDato;
    struct ejemplo *sgte;
};
```

Para crear un nodo (en este caso con un float), haremos lo siguiente (supongo que **a** es un puntero al nodo)

```
a->valor.datoFloat = 5.3;
a->tipoDato = 2; // Tipo float
a->sgte = NULL;
```

Para recuperar el valor de un nodo **a**, si no sabemos previamente su tipo, lo podemos hacer así:

```
switch(a->tipoDato){
    case 0:
        valorChar = a->valor.datoChar;
        break;
    case 1:
        valorInt = a->valor.datoInt;
        break;
    case 2:
        valorFloat = a->valor.datoFloat;
        break;
}
```

En el caso de que los datos sean complejos, como strings o estructuras, la cosa se complicaría un poco. En este caso yo haría que el campo **valor** de tu estructura sea un puntero a un dato indefinido (void) y luego asignaría dinámicamente la memoria en la que se almacena el dato. Hay que tener en cuenta, en este caso, que al eliminar el nodo se deberá liberar la memoria. Algo así, la estructura sería:

```
struct ejemplo{
    void *valor;
    char tipoDato;
    struct ejemplo *sgte;
};
```

Veamos como crear un nodo con un string (array de chars)

```
a->valor = malloc(11);
strcpy(a->valor, "Hola mundo");
a->tipoDato = 0; // Supongo que el tipo 0 es un tipo string
a->sgte = NULL;
```

En el caso de que el dato sea una estructura lo haríamos así (vamos a suponer que tenemos una estructura ya creada y llamada **Cliente**)

```
a->valor = malloc(sizeof(Cliente));
((Cliente *)a->valor).Edad = ...; // Rellenamos los datos de la estructura Cliente
...
a->tipoDato = 1; // Supongo que el tipo 1 es un tipo Cliente
a->sgte = NULL;
```

Por último, al eliminar el nodo debemos recordar liberar la memoria

```
free(a->valor);
```